# How to make the correct page selection in datatables when selecting a row?

Tags: datatables

The code I'm working with will highlight the corresponding row in the data tables after clicking on the map marker.

The problem is that when sorting is applied, the selection of the page with the selected row is incorrect or does not occur at all.

If I cancel the pagination by displaying all the lines, then the line selection works perfectly fine. How to make correct **page** selection when selecting row after sorting?

```
 // Add markers and event listeners
  for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker([dataArray[i][5], dataArray[i][6]]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("Book: " + dataArray[i][2] + "<br>" + "Pages: " + dataArray[i][3]);

var currentMarker = null;
var currentTableRow = null;

marker.on("click", function(e) {
   var popup = e.target.getPopup();
   var content = popup.getContent();
   var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
   var rowData = table.rows().data().toArray();

   // Find the row that matches the content of the popup
   var tr = null;
   for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
     if (rowData[i][2] == content.split("<br>")[0].split(": ")[1]) {
       // Use the "index" option to get the index of the row in the original loading order
       var index = table.column(2, {order:'index'}).data().indexOf(rowData[i][2]);
       tr = table.row(index).node();
       break;
     }
   }

   if (tr !== null) {
     // Add a "highlight" class to the new table row
     $(tr).addClass("highlight");

     // Remove the "highlight" class from the previous table row (if any)
     if (currentTableRow !== null) {
       $(currentTableRow).removeClass("highlight");
     }

     // Update the currently selected marker and its corresponding table row
     currentMarker = marker;
     currentTableRow = tr;

     // Get the page index of the selected row
     var pageInfo = table.page.info();
     var rowPage = Math.floor(table.row(tr).index() / pageInfo.length);

     // Set the page index as the active page
     table.page(rowPage).draw(false);
   }
});


  }
```

Comment: Can you convert your example into a snippet or a JSFiddle so we could play around with it? Currently a lot of context for your question is missing and makes it very hard to understand your exact situation accurately.

Comment: Minor point, but I agree with @LajosArpad - it would be better to provide the full context (as a [mre]) in your question. I have assumed this question is similar to a previous Leaflet/DataTables question you asked - and I have based my answer on that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Instead of this:

```
tr = table.row(index).node();
```

use this:

```
tr = table.row(index, {order:'index'}).node();
```

---

**Explanation:**

Your code is using the following:

```
var index = table.column(2, {order:'index'})
```

This retrieves the index value assigned to the row in DataTables. This value is assigned when the DataTable is first initialized and represents the original order in which data was loaded into your DataTable. This assigned value does not change, regardless of what filtering or sorting you apply.

You therefore need to use this same `index` value **with the same [selector-modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier)** when you select the node to be highlighted.

If you only use `tr = table.row(index).node();`, then this defaults to `{order:'current'}` - which is why you get the wrong (or no) row highlighted.

---

**Demo:**

I added `lengthMenu: [ 2, 10 ],` to my demo, just to show multiple pages for my test data.

```js
var dataArray = [
  ['111', '1111', 'AAA', '752', 'Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.11'],
  ['222', '5555', 'BBB', ' 1040', 'Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.10'],
  ['333', '777', 'CCC', '846', 'Hardcover', '51.565', '-0.11'],
  ['444', '888', 'DDD', '258', 'Paperback', '51.56', '-0.12'],
  ['555', '555', 'FFF', ' 789', 'Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.13']
];

var map = L.map('viewmap').setView([51.56, -0.12], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  var marker = L.marker([dataArray[i][5], dataArray[i][6]]).addTo(map);
  marker.bindPopup("Book: " + dataArray[i][2] + "<br>" + "Pages: " + dataArray[i][3]);

  var currentMarker = null;
  var currentTableRow = null;

  marker.on("click", function(e) {
    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
    var content = popup.getContent();
    var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
    var rowData = table.rows().data().toArray();

    // Find the row that matches the content of the popup
    var tr = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
      if (rowData[i][2] == content.split("<br>")[0].split(": ")[1]) {
        // Use the "index" option to get the index of the row in the original loading order
        var index = table.column(2, {order: 'index'}).data().indexOf(rowData[i][2]);
        tr = table.row(index, {order: 'index'}).node();
        break;
      }
    }

    if (tr !== null) {
      // Add a "highlight" class to the new table row
      $(tr).addClass("highlight");

      // Remove the "highlight" class from the previous table row (if any)
      if (currentTableRow !== null) {
        $(currentTableRow).removeClass("highlight");
      }

      // Update the currently selected marker and its corresponding table row
      currentMarker = marker;
      currentTableRow = tr;

      // Get the page index of the selected row
      var pageInfo = table.page.info();
      var rowPage = Math.floor(table.row(tr).index() / pageInfo.length);

      // Set the page index as the active page
      table.page(rowPage).draw(false);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#data-table').DataTable({
    data: dataArray,
    lengthMenu: [ 2, 10 ],
    columns: [{
        "title": "Rating"
      },
      {
        "title": "Reviews"
      },
      {
        "title": "Book"
      },
      {
        "title": "Pages"
      },
      {
        "title": "Type"
      },
      {
        "title": "Longitude"
      },
      {
        "title": "Latitude"
      },
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

  <?!= include('Scriptdata'); ?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      #viewmap {
        width: 60%;
        height: 60vh;
        left: 0%;
        margin: auto;
      }
      
      #text {
        font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      }
      
      .highlight {
        background-color: yellow !important;
        ;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="viewmap"></div>

</body>



</html>
```

---

**Update**

Regarding your comment:

> I click the "Pages" filter ... does not go to the page with the highlighted line.

You can use the DataTables [`length`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/length) event to know when the user changes the DataTable "rows per page" drop-down. You can then use similar code to what you already have in your demo (and in my demo) to ensure the required row is still visible after a page length change:

```js
$('#data-table').on( 'length.dt', function ( e, settings, len ) {
  if (tr !== null) {
    var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
    var pageInfo = table.page.info();
    var rowPage = Math.floor(table.row(tr).index() / pageInfo.length);
    table.page(rowPage).draw(false);
  }
} );
```

For example:

1. I show all 10 pages in my demo.
2. I highlight row `DDD`.
3. I change the drop-down from 10 pages to 2 pages.
4. Row `DDD` is still visible.

Some additional re-organization is needed from my original demo. Here is the new `<script>` code:

```
  var tr = null;

  var dataArray = [
    ['111', '1111', 'AAA', '752', 'Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.11'], 
    ['222', '5555', 'BBB',' 1040', 'Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.10'], 
    ['333', '777','CCC', '846', 'Hardcover', '51.565', '-0.11'], 
    ['444', '888', 'DDD','258','Paperback', '51.56', '-0.12'], 
    ['555', '555', 'FFF',' 789','Hardcover', '51.55', '-0.13']
  ];

  var map = L.map('viewmap').setView([51.56, -0.12], 13);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);
    
  for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker([dataArray[i][5], dataArray[i][6]]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("Book: " + dataArray[i][2] + "<br>" + "Pages: " + dataArray[i][3]);

    var currentMarker = null;
    var currentTableRow = null;

    marker.on("click", function(e) {
      var popup = e.target.getPopup();
      var content = popup.getContent();
      var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
      var rowData = table.rows().data().toArray();

      // Find the row that matches the content of the popup
      //var tr = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
        if (rowData[i][2] == content.split("<br>")[0].split(": ")[1]) {
          // Use the "index" option to get the index of the row in the original loading order
          var index = table.column(2, {order:'index'}).data().indexOf(rowData[i][2]);
          tr = table.row(index, {order:'index'}).node();
          break;
        }
      }

      if (tr !== null) {
        // Add a "highlight" class to the new table row
        $(tr).addClass("highlight");

        // Remove the "highlight" class from the previous table row (if any)
        if (currentTableRow !== null) {
          $(currentTableRow).removeClass("highlight");
        }

        // Update the currently selected marker and its corresponding table row
        currentMarker = marker;
        currentTableRow = tr;

        // Get the page index of the selected row
        var pageInfo = table.page.info();
        var rowPage = Math.floor(table.row(tr).index() / pageInfo.length);

        // Set the page index as the active page
        table.page(rowPage).draw(false);
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
      data: dataArray,
      "lengthMenu": [ 2, 10 ],
      columns: [
        {"title":"Rating"},
        {"title":"Reviews"},
        {"title":"Book"},
        {"title":"Pages"},
        {"title":"Type"},
        {"title":"Longitude"},
        {"title":"Latitude"},
      ]
    });
  });

  $('#data-table').on( 'length.dt', function ( e, settings, len ) {
    if (tr !== null) {
      var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
      var pageInfo = table.page.info();
      var rowPage = Math.floor(table.row(tr).index() / pageInfo.length);
      table.page(rowPage).draw(false);
    }
  } );
```

I am sure you could refactor this to improve it (e.g. by moving common code into a function). But this should give you a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I can't insert an array into a comment
I tested the original script on an array of 15 lines, split 10 by page (10+5).
The problem remains, after sorting (Number of Pages) not all markers correctly display lines.
In fact, they stand out, but not on their page!

Comment: Understood. Can you provide a [mre] or identify the differences between your code and the code in this answer (which does handle paging correctly)?

Comment: Mot actions with your code, when broken down into 2 lines.
1) Lines and pages are highlighted correctly.
everything works correctly and line selection and page transitions
2) I click the "Pages" filter
3) click on markers:
AAA-ok
BBB - does not go to the page with the highlighted line
CCC - ok
DDD - does not go to the page with the highlighted line
FFF - does not go to the page with the highlighted line

Comment: I am not sure I completely understood your comment, but I have added some new details to my answer. I think (maybe) it answers your comments.

Comment: Can I make two additional suggestions? (1) Generally, (in future questions you ask) please add clarifications into your question, instead of adding them as comments - they belong in the question. (2) If my updates here do not address your comments, then maybe you can ask a brand new question, with a runnable MRE (similar to my runnable MREs in this answer) and also provide the steps needed to recreate whatever problem still exists.

Comment: yes, the question was not complete and without a specific example. I did not add to the question that the selection of the line when changing the page should remain.  Thank you!